# sentence that appear the most using tfidf in my dataframe with python

Tags: python, csv, dataframe, tokenize, tf-idf

I want to look for the sentence that appear the most using tfidf in my dataframe, I did some preprocessing as tokenize and stopword, and now I have 2 columns (text & Stopword)

```
text                                                                   Stopword
bts jimin declared himself the worst player after his self sabotage    ['bts', 'jimin', 'declared','worst', 'player', 'self', 'sabotage']
bts ultra practical suga turned their game into an economy lesson      ['bts', 'ultra', 'practical', 'suga', 'turned', 'game', 'economy', 'lesson']
the mystery of bts sunflowers has finally been solved                  ['mystery', 'bts', 'sunflowers', 'finally', 'solved']
```

i want to get dataframe with sentence from Stopword column which the value is the tf_idf and the columns are the words like this

```
bts           tf_idf
mystery       tf_idf
suga          tf_idf
jimin         tf_idf
declared      tf_idf
worst         tf_idf
player        tf_idf
safe          tf_idf
sabotage      tf_idf
practical     tf_idf
turned        tf_idf
game          tf_idf
economy       tf_idf
lesson        tf_idf
sunflower     tf_idf
finally       tf_idf
solved        tf_idf
```

maybe someone here knows the code and can help me?

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like there's a lot of equations to [tf-idf](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf). I'm unsure which one to use, but once you decide I would do something like:

```py
def tf_idf(word):
  # do stuff
  return stuff

output = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
  for word in row:
    output.append([word, tf_idf(word)])

output = pd.DataFrame(data=output, columns=["Word", "TF_IDF"])
```